# How to spell-check abbreviations?

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, affix, hunspell, myspell

I'm using [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) which is based on MySpell and I can't work out how to spell-check words with apostrophes in the middle.

I'm testing it on the command line from Max OS X Terminal, as per the following example:

This phrase has single quotes and an apostrophe (all using ASCII 0x27 `'`)

```
He doesn't like 'Big Jon'
```

I am saving this file in `test.txt` and then running the `hunspell` program as follows to show spelling errors:

```
~$ /usr/bin/hunspell -d en-GB -l test.txt
doesn
```

This prints `"doesn"` as a failed spelling. All other words pass, including the chopped off `"t"`.

The word `doesn't` **is** in my dictionary. (downloaded from Mozilla)

I can force the dictionary to not split the words by adding `WORDCHARS '` to the Affix file (en-GB.aff) but then the quoted words are picked up as misspelled, so I get:

```
~$ /usr/bin/hunspell -d en-GB -l test.txt
'Big
Jon'
```

Is there a way (without pre-processing the text) to match the valid abbreviations AND decapse quotations?

Comment: What language is `~$ echo`?

Comment: Just command line. will add to Quesiton

Comment: According to [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), the way you escape single quotes at the command line is `^'`.  So `doesn't` becomes `doesn^'t`.  It's probably not going to matter in any other context but the command line, though.

Comment: that's a DOS article. I'm on Mac/Unix. Have updated question again with that.

Comment: Ahem.  `\'` then. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/inline-double-and-single-quote-escaping

Comment: This isn't the issue. Proven by the fact the result is the same when piped from file.

Comment: Try `~$ echo "He doesn\'t like 'Big Jon'" | hunspell -d en-GB -l` and tell me what it does.

Comment: I have. before I wrote that this isn't the issue.